# Invalid Key Hash (Facebook Login)

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an app that includes Facebook Login. Everything working fine in Development mode. But after publishing my app on the Play store. I encountered an error saying:
"invalid key hash facebook android does not match any stored"
Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't changed the default settings, then Google has generated a signing key for you in the Google Play console. The Play Store uses this key then to sign your APK. You can check the signing key signature in the Google Play Store console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is telling you that you have not added the signed key hash, which is generated when your app is published on the Play store, to your Facebook app yet.
Steps:
Check if the release key hash is added to your Facebook app.

1. If not, generate your release key hash by using this command:
   keytool -exportcert -alias  -keystore  | openssl sha1 -binary
   | openssl base64
2. Add that key hash to the Basic Settings of the Facebook app.
3. Since you have published your app, go to the Play store console -> Setup -> App Integrity.
4. Copy the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from the App signing key certificate section.
5. Then visit the below link, paste the key hash to generate the signed key hash.
6. Copy that signed key [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h41e.png)hash and paste it to the Basic Settings of your Facebook app.